# Changing the root folder on my vsftp server

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, vsftpd

I new to this so followed this [walkthrough](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04) to set up a vsftp server on an Ubuntu 16.04 box. With this configuration I managed to log into my ftp server and upload/download files but the thing is that I have to enter the server and then enter the subfolder which has read/write access for the user logging in. I tried to change the ftp root folder by changing

`local_root=/home/$USER/ftp`

to

`local_root=/home/$USER/ftp/files`

But this gives me `GnuTLS error -15: An unexpected TLS packet was received.` when I reload the server setting and try to connect.

Is there something I'm missing? What would be a recommended approach to configure vsftp so that user logs directly into its read/write folder. TLS connection is required.

Comment: tls had ususally nothing to do with the root dir

Comment: Could you show the rest of your configuration?
Maybe there is some TLS - Config depending on $local_root, but this is hard to say without knowing your whole config...

Answer (score 1):

My solution is following:

I had to add following to vsftpd.conf

```
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
chroot_local_user=YES 
local_root=/home/$USER/ftp/files
user_sub_token=$USER
ssl_enable=NO --optional-- to get rid of the error
```

Comment: tried this but ssl is a requirement... still get same error